Using VBA to query SSMS
I currently create views and connect them to my excel files. However, when I do ad hoc analysis I just query and copy results into excel. Is there a way to use VBA to query the server directly?
not sure what to do once I right click and view code

I would change your question to specify MSSQL instead of SSMS.  SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio: the IDE for browsing MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server).

This question is similar to: Using Excel VBA to run SQL query. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also, you can't query SSMS. SSMS is a tool for writing SQL for SQL Server (the actual database engine that gets queried). It's important to learn the difference between the database engine (SQL Server) and the tool used to manage it (SSMS). They're not the same thing.
